# Do function parameters take up local memory space?

Tags: c, memory

In the following example, am I taking up any local memory space in the function "add"? And if not, where are the parameter variables stored in memory?

```
void add(int *a, int *b, int *result){

  *result = *a + *b;

} 

int main(){

  int a = 1, b = 2, result;

  add(&a, &b, &result);

  printf("Result = %d\n", result);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "local memory space"?

Comment: Do you mean the stack?

Comment: This is an implementation detail which might vary for different compilers (although most compilers follow a similar strategy).

Comment: I mean the storage inside the stack-frame that is allocated for the function "add". Are the function parameters stored the same way within the stack-frame as other local variables are? Sorry if I make no sense

Comment: There is no stack in the C language. This word does not even show up in the standard text. That function will possibly not even exist as entity, less be called in your final program code. How about some research on your own? Learning by reading/own research is much more satisfying and successful.

Answer (score 1):

> Do function parameters take up local memory space?
>
> In the following example, am I taking up any local memory space in the function "add"?

The answer to these questions depends **heavily** upon your implementation. Perhaps your implementation *automatically inlines the functions*, and so those *function parameters* might be *eliminated entirely* by the inlining process. Your implementation might even *hoist some of your runtime logic into compile time*; i.e. your entire example can be optimised to `puts("Result = 2");` during compilation.

Alternatively...

> where are the parameter variables stored in memory?

Often times, arguments are stored into register storage. The register storage is committed to the program, and might otherwise be *committed and unused*; it'd be a waste *not* to use it for this purpose.

Suffice to say, C doesn't require that *register storage* exist, and so that shouldn't be relied upon. At the end of the day, **you shouldn't care where variables are stored**; all that should matter is that *they are stored*.

Stack, heap, register... who cares? It's all the same place, in the same computer, right? The only time it makes a difference is when you're optimising, and for the sake of avoiding *premature optimisation* you should only ask this question *at the time of optimisation, and with a scope appropriate to the optimisation*.

Comment: Register access and access to hot (cached) memory seem pretty close. On x86-64 Linux, the first 6 integers are passed via registers and the rest via memory, but for like 8, 9 arguments, I wasn't able to measure any significant increase in the function call overhead, so I guess there's hardly much of a point in trying very hard to minimize function arguments for the sake of performance.

Comment: @PSkocik: That massively depends on the whole control flow. If there is cahce trashing, you will experience massive differences. Worse, if there is DRAM-bank closing/opening. Said that: without more details, the question si way too broad for this site.

Comment: @Seb I'm not attacking your answer. You have my upvote. I only commented about trying to optimize this sort of stuff. Never mind the comment.

Comment: @PSkocik Fair enough. In that case, I've removed my lengthy comment as it suffices to say, not all implementations are x86-64.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the function calling convention, parameters are either stored on the stack or in processor registers.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: Or the compiler just optimizes the whole thing out and the parameters aren't stored at all.